# first time writing an Angular directives and returning a compiled template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write my first directive and am a bit confused. I would like to return a compiled template where the ng-click is functional. I have (http://plnkr.co/edit/gr3ha1lxgcFp3z4L148S?p=preview ):

```
var arcModule=angular.module('Octo', []);


arcModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.sayHello=function(){
    alert("hello");
  }
});  

Octo.directive('myCustomer', function() {
        return {
            template: 'Name: <div ng-click="sayHello()">say hello</div> Address: '
        };
});
```

In my plnkr, why is the my-customer directive not being outputted?

But am a bit clueless as to what the next step is. I kinda get the concept of linking and compiling but am not sure how to implement. How could I do this? The docs are like molasses and I feel what I'm doing is incredibly simple.

thx for any help

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're actually using your directive anywhere in your markup.

Comment: thx @Zajn shouldn't `<div my-customer></div>` be calling it? I feel like there's possibly a syntax error in my simple directive since the first ng-click isn't working. I know directives are critical so just trying to expose myself to them as best as I can.

Comment: Yes, that will make it show up, at least. When I loaded your plunkr, I didn't see `<div my-customer></div>` anywhere. I think m59 answered your question anyway!

Comment: yes, I think he did. First using plunkr too so a lot of moving parts. thx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having, which is not clear in your code above is that you're overwriting the controller that has the click function defined.

You have this twice in your code: `arcModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {`

All I did to make your directive work was remove the second controller definition so that the first one with the click function is used (you really just need to combine them). Then added `<div my-customer></div>` to the DOM. The directive kicked in and added the directive markup and the click function worked properly.

Here's your full code corrected: [Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/KoHDmWNmEZZR5UJl1NNM?p=preview)

**JavaScript:**

```
var arcModule=angular.module('Octo', []);

arcModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.sayHello=function(){
    alert("hello");
  }
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
});  

arcModule.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}<button ng-click="sayHello()">Click to say hello.</button> Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<body ng-app="Octo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div my-customer></div>
```

Comment: thx @m59 , so would that template be considered `compiled`? I would think so since it's just be rendered out upon first load (or maybe not if `compiled` only makes sense for fresh html that is written into the dom. Thx again.

Comment: @timpone yes, it is compiled. If it weren't the data-binding wouldn't be working. The `template` parameter is automatically compiled and so is the compile function, of course. If you used the link function to add markup, then you have to compile manually.