# return a template when a user clicks on an event in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to grok the syntax for angular (just started yesterday) and the best way to achieve the following. What I'd like to do is load some compiled html and inject it into the DOM. This is a follow-up to this question: [first time writing an Angular directives and returning a compiled template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695286/first-time-writing-an-angular-directives-and-returning-a-compiled-template) . Rather than call

```
<div my-customer></div>
```

I'd like to load the template dynamically based upon user interaction. Say something like:

```
<div ng-click="loadMyCustomer()">load customer</div><!-- should load here -->
....

arcModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.sayHello(){
    alert("hello here");
  }

  $scope.loadMyCustomer=function(){
    //alert("hello");
    // return the template in the mycustomer directive and place it after the current DOM element from which it is called 
  }
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
});

arcModule.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}<button ng-click="sayHello()">Click to say hello.</button> Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

Sorry if this sounds simple but I find Angular docs a bit opaque and, if I can figure out how to return this, I'll be very happy. So, how would I return the template in the directive via the loadMyCustomer method?

Answer (score 0):

For what you have highlighted it can be done without creating new directive and using the current `ng-include` directive.

Even if you have to do it this way

```
<div ng-click="showCustomer=true">...
<div my-customer ng-if="showCustomer"></div>
```

The advantage of `ngif` is that the template would not be loaded till the `showCustomer` is true.